# A duplicate number is printed in the C++ threadpool

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, threadpool

threadpool.h

```cpp
#ifndef THREADPOOL
#define THREADPOOL 


#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <list> 
#include <condition_variable>

template <typename T>
class Threadpool
{
public:
    static int nums;
    
    Threadpool() : _threadSize(8), _queueMaxsize(100)
    {

    }
    Threadpool(int threadSize, int queueMaxsize) : _threadSize(threadSize), _queueMaxsize(queueMaxsize), m_stop(false)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<_threadSize; ++i)
        {
            threads.push_back(std::thread(worker,this,i));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < _threadSize; ++i)
        {
            threads[i].detach();
        }
    }

    bool append(T * request)
    {
        if (workQueue.size() > _queueMaxsize)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(queueLock);
        workQueue.push_back(request);
        //request->process();
        guard.unlock();
        m_cond.notify_one();
    }
    void printQueueSize()
    {
        std::cout<<workQueue.size()<<std::endl;
    }
private:
    static void worker(void * args, int threadId)
    {
        Threadpool *threadpool=(Threadpool*) args;
        threadpool->run(threadId); 
    }

    void run(int threadId)
    {
        while(!m_stop)
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(queueLock);
            m_cond.wait(lk,[this]{return !this->workQueue.empty();});
            T* request = workQueue.front();
            workQueue.pop_front();
            std::cout<<"thread"<<threadId<<" process ";
            request->process();
            //std::cout<<request->_s<<std::endl;
            this->nums++;
        }
    }
    
private:
    int _threadSize;
    int _queueMaxsize;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::mutex queueLock;
    std::condition_variable m_cond;
    std::list<T *> workQueue;
    bool m_stop;

};

template<class T>
int Threadpool<T>::nums = 0;



#endif // THREADPOOL
```

test.cpp

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include "threadpool.h"


class Request 
{
public:
    explicit Request(std::string s):_s(s){}
    void process()
    {
        printf("%s\n",_s.c_str());
        fflush(stdout);
    }
// private:
    std::string _s;

};
int main()
{
    Threadpool<Request>  threadpool(10,100);
    

    for(int i =0; i<100; i++)
    {
        std::string str = std::string("job"+std::to_string(i));
        //std::cout<<str<<std::endl;
        Request r1 (str);
        //r1.process();
        threadpool.append(&r1);
        //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(50));
        
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));

    std::cout<< Threadpool<Request>::nums<<std::endl;
    // std::cout<<"fuck"<<std::endl

    threadpool.printQueueSize();
    return 0;
}
```

I want to create a thread pool and print numbers between 1 -> 1000. However, the result is not what I expected.
The result is showed below,

```cpp
thread0 process job2  
thread0 process job2  
thread1 process job5  
thread1 process job5  
thread1 process job5  
thread3 process job6  
thread6 process job9  
thread6 process job9  
thread6 process job9  
thread9 process job14  
thread9 process job14  
thread9 process job14  
thread9 process job14  
thread9 process job14  
thread0 process job15  
thread6 process job19  
thread6 process job19   
thread6 process job19  
thread6 process job19  
thread8 process job21  
thread4 process job21  
thread8 process job22  
thread3 process job23  
thread1 process job25  
thread1 process job25  
thread6 process job28  
thread6 process job28  
thread6 process job28  
thread6 process job28  
thread4 process job30  
thread8 process job31  
thread9 process job32  
thread0 process job35  
thread0 process job35  
thread0 process job35  
thread6 process job37  
thread6 process job37  
thread4 process job39  
thread4 process job39  
thread2 process job41  
thread2 process job41  
thread0 process job45  
thread0 process job45  
thread5 process job45  
thread5 process job45  
thread5 process job45  
thread5 process job46  
thread3 process job47  
thread0 process job49  
thread8 process job50  
thread2 process job51  
thread9 process job53  
thread9 process job53  
thread5 process job54  
thread6 process job55  
thread1 process job56  
thread4 process job57   
thread3 process job58  
thread0 process job59  
thread8 process job60  
thread2 process job61  
thread9 process job62  
thread5 process job63  
thread7 process job64  
thread6 process job65  
thread1 process job66  
thread4 process job67  
thread3 process job68  
thread0 process job69  
thread8 process job70  
thread2 process job71  
thread9 process job72    
thread5 process job73   
thread7 process job74       
thread6 process job75  
thread1 process job76    
thread3 process job78  
thread3 process job78     
thread8 process job80  
thread8 process job80   
thread9 process job82  
thread9 process job82  
thread9 process job82  
thread9 process job83  
thread7 process job84   
thread1 process job87  
thread1 process job87  
thread0 process job89  
thread0 process job89  
thread0 process job89  
thread2 process job91  
thread9 process job93  
thread9 process job93  
thread7 process job96  
thread7 process job96  
thread7 process job96  
thread3 process job98  
thread3 process job98  
thread2 process job99  
thread2 process job99  
100  
0
```

I have already checked the size of queue. And it is empty. Is it about the cache of the stdout or my threadpool is wrong?

Comment: Well, what *did* you expect? And why?

Comment: I expect that there are no repeated numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have UB in your code, you capture `r1` by reference but the local variable goes out of scope by next iteration making access through the reference undefined behaviour.

Since the compiler most likely reuses the storage for `r1`s, `printf("%s\n",_s.c_str());` in `process` will use the currently present value written there concurrently(=>race condition) by the loop.
This is why you get some repeated values. You are lucky there are no segfaults though. Again, all of this is undefined.

I suggest you store the `Request` objects directly in the `workQueue`, use move semantics for `append`.

Whenever you deal will multi-threading, try to use the thread sanitizer - add `-fsanitize=thread` to gcc and clang. It is really a valuable tool for these kind of bugs.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I'm new to multithreaded development. I will try to use the thread sanitizer to solve the multithread problem.

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with multithreading though. It's just a part of the C++ object model that you've been missing.